# class in C# doesn't recognize Image class from System.Drawing

Tags: c#, image, user-interface

I was writing my `Patient` class, for clinic software, and wanted to add a `Photo` property, but the `Image` class doesn't seem to be working in my code, don't know why, considering that I have included `System.Drawing`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ClinicFiles
{
    public partial class Patient : Person
    {
        public Image Photo { get; set; }
        //etc. etc.
    }
}
```

P.S. What site do you find the best guideline to a beautiful Windows Application design? :) Nice and professional user interface, all details taken care of, as fonts, etc etc. :)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to be working", what is happening (or not happening)? Are you getting an error?  What does it say?

Comment: Make sure your project has the dll referenced.

Comment: When you say that you've included `System.Drawing`, do you mean that you added it as a reference or you've just added the `using` statement for it?

Comment: @AnnL. it doesn't recognize it as type, I don't even have a class Image in auto-suggest list when I write System.Drawing.

Comment: @itsme86 oh, I thought I have done it XD but then I checked it again. XD U are right, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try right-clicking your project References and adding System.Drawing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I hate this answer because it doesn't have hand-drawn arrows. +1 anyway though :P